# Combine values of two arrays to form key and values to hash in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

If i have two arrays containing about 20 separate values is it possible to combine the two into a hash? With the contents of one array acting as the keys and the other as the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, very simple

```
Hash[[1,2,3,4].zip([5,6,7,8])]
 => {1=>5, 2=>6, 3=>7, 4=>8}
```

But it might be a problem if the arrays have not the same size.

Comment: I wonder how sometimes answers appear after the question is closed/marked as duplicate/whatever else - might be a bug or something in SO :)

Comment: Probably I answered one second before :P

Comment: hm, I am sure (at least on the GUI) that when I marked it as duplicate there were no questions, and even more - I reloaded the page and still it didn't have the answer, so interesting :)

Comment: @ursus Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)